# What does select * from table(Get... mean?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've been sent a short piece of SQL code by someone in IT. I have a decent understanding of SQL, but am not familiar with the `table(Get...` syntax in the below code. Searching for `table` and `get` in Google return a lot results not applicable to me.

`select * from table(Get('COMPANY_X', '31-MAR-2017', NULL,'Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y'))`

I'm hoping someone can explain what I'm looking at, or tell me what keyword I should search for.

Thank you for your help

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions

Comment: That answers my question. Thank you.